# Finding all the keys with the same value in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary:

```
dict1 = {"Jim": "y", "Bob": "y", "Ravioli": "n"}  # etc.
```

I want to print out all the keys with the value "y" (i.e: "Jim", "Bob"). How do I achieve this (in the simplest way possible)?

Comment: `[i for i,j in dic.items() if j == 'y']`

Comment: It seems like your actual problem is your dictionary is backwards, with `{'y': ['Jim', ...], ...}` you can get your answer in `O(1)`.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest that answer only finds one of the keys with a certain value

Comment: The top answer in the link provided returns all the values (and not just one).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use this:

```
[k for k, v in dict1.items() if v == 'y']
```

Result:

```
['Bob', 'Jim']
```

Comment: "And please don't use dict as a variable name." hahah I know, that was just a theoretical question for clarity

Comment: How will it be used for multiple outputs? i.e. if I have to print for v == 'y' and lets assume v == 'x' and so on

Comment: @SrijanChaudhary Then you can change the if condition like this `if v in ('x','y','z')`

Comment: @RahulKP but this will be a very inefficient way to do, and it is somewhat doing a hard code, what if we don't know all the values?